# Использует ли boost::asio ssl-кеш?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl

Если посмотреть, скажем, на сервер *imap.gmail.com*, то можно заметить, что он кеширует ssl-сессии. А значит, можно поддержать это кеширование со стороны клиента, чтобы снизить нагрузку на сервер.

Поддерживает ли *boost::asio* такую возможность? Если поддерживает, то вопросы:

1. Если *boost::asio::ssl::stream* не использует кеш ssl-сессий, как я могу включить использование?
2. Если *boost::asio::ssl::stream* использует кеш ssl-сессий, как я могу выключить использование? :)

Или данную опцию надо настраивать как-то непосредственно силами openssl? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*boost::asio* не поддерживает механизм кеширования ssl-сессий напрямую. Но, поскольку *boost::asio::ssl::stream* хранит внутри себя объект SSL_SESSION (это объект из библиотеки openssl), то такое кеширование несложно сделать самому.

Примерная реализация может быть такой:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23_client);
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> backend(io, ctx); 

// заводим какой-нибудь объект, в котором будем хранить кеш
std::map<std::string, SSL_SESSION*> ssl_cache;

// после успешного коннекта складываем сессию в кеш
SSL_SESSION *session = SSL_get1_session(backend.native_handle());
ssl_cache[host] = session;

// перед тем, как выполнять коннект на сервер host, проверим кеш
auto cached_session = ssl_cache.find(host);
if (cached_session != ssl_cache.end())
{
    SSL_SESSION *session = cached_session->second;
    SSL_set_session(backend.native_handle(), session);
}

// после коннекта можно проверить, была ли ssl-сессия использована повторно
if (SSL_session_reused(backend.native_handle()))
{
    // reused
}
```

---

Надо заметить, что данный подход поддерживает оба механизма кеширования:

- ssl-тикеты (RFC 5077)
- идентификаторы сессий (RFC 5246)

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSL предоставляет опцию, которая разрешает/запрещает использование кешированных сессий - [SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode/SSL_CTX_get_session_cache_mode](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode.html). Т.е., если boost имеет к этому какое-то отношение, то ищите в нем вызовы этих функций.

А вот и [вопрос-близнец](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226390/does-boostasio-use-ssl-session-cache) cо SO.

Тут подсказывают, что boost может предоставлять/принимать native handle `SSL_CTX` в подобных случаях.

Comment: вопрос-близнец я же и задавал ). на самом деле я уже разобрался и хотел ответить на свой же вопрос - с примером кода - только все времени не хватает.